# Why does this decision tree's values at each step not sum to the number of samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm reading about decision trees and bagging classifiers, and I'm trying to show the first decision tree that is used in the bagging classifier.  I'm confused about the output.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from graphviz import Source

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=0.30, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

bag_clf = BaggingClassifier(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
    n_estimators=500,
    max_samples=100, 
    bootstrap=True, 
    n_jobs=-1)
bag_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

Source(tree.export_graphviz(bag_clf.estimators_[0], out_file=None))
```

Here's a snippet out of the output

[image]

It's been my understanding that the `value` is supposed to show how many of the samples are classified as each category.  In that case, shouldn't the numbers in the `value` field add up to the `samples` field?  Why is that not the case here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch.

It would seem that the extra bootstrap samples are included in the `value`, but not in the total `samples`; repeating your code verbatim but changing to `bootstrap=False` eliminates the discrepancy:

[image]

The behavior is similar in Random Forest, both classifier and regressor - see respectively:

- [Why the sum "value" isn't equal to the number of "samples" in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639534/why-the-sum-value-isnt-equal-to-the-number-of-samples-in-scikit-learn-rando/71644712)
- [sklearn RandomForestRegressor discrepancy in the displayed tree values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920980/sklearn-randomforestregressor-discrepancy-in-the-displayed-tree-values)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting find.

I did some dig around and found that the bootstrapping switches on the proportion = True switch while exporting the graphviz object. Since there is possibility of same sample passing through the decision tree more than once, it is expressed in percentage terms. If bootstrapping = False, the sample goes through only once and hence it can be expressed as sample counts on each classes.