# Why the sum "value" isn't equal to the number of "samples" in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I built a random forest by RandomForestClassifier and plot the decision trees. What does the parameter "value" (pointed by red arrows) mean? And why the sum of two numbers in the [] doesn't equal to the number of "samples"? I saw some other examples, the sum of two numbers in the [] equals to the number of "samples". Why in my case, it doesn't?

```
df = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv")
df.drop(['Flow ID', 'Inbound'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df.Label[df.Label == 'BENIGN'] = 0
df.Label[df.Label == 'DrDoS_LDAP'] = 1
Y = df["Label"].values
Y = Y.astype('int')
X = df.drop(labels = ["Label"], axis=1)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.5)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 20)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Accuracy = model.score(X_test, Y_test)
        
for i in range(len(model.estimators_)):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    tree.plot_tree(model.estimators_[i], feature_names = df.columns, class_names = ['Benign', 'DDoS'])
    plt.savefig('.\\TheForest\\T'+str(i))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice catch.

Although undocumented, this is due to the **bootstrap sampling** taking place by default in a Random Forest model (see my answer in [Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif) for more on the RF algorithm details and its difference from a mere "bunch" of decision trees).

Let's see an example with the `iris` data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

iris = load_iris()

rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 3)
rf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[0]) # take the first tree
```

[image]

The result here is similar to what you report: for every other node except the lower right one, `sum(value)` does not equal `samples`, as it should be the case for [a "simple" decision tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719001/what-does-scikit-learn-decisiontreeclassifier-tree-value-do).

A cautious observer would have noticed something else which seems odd here: while the iris dataset has 150 samples:

```
print(iris.DESCR)

.. _iris_dataset:

Iris plants dataset
--------------------

**Data Set Characteristics:**

    :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)
    :Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class
```

and the base node of the tree should include all of them, the `samples` for the first node are only 89.

Why is that, and what exactly is going on here? To see, let us fit a second RF model, this time **without bootstrap sampling** (i.e. with `bootstrap=False`):

```
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 3, bootstrap=False) # no bootstrap sampling
rf2.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

tree.plot_tree(rf2.estimators_[0]) # take again the first tree
```

[image]

Well, now that we have disabled bootstrap sampling, everything looks "nice": the sum of `value` in every node equals `samples`, and the base node contains indeed the whole dataset (150 samples).

So, the behavior you describe seems to be due to bootstrap sampling indeed, which, while creating samples *with replacement* (i.e. ending up with *duplicate* samples for each individual decision tree of the ensemble), these duplicate samples are not reflected in the `sample` values of the tree nodes, which display the number of *unique* samples; nevertheless, it *is* reflected in the node `value`.

The situation is completely analogous with that of a RF regression model, as well as with a Bagging Classifier - see respectively:

- [sklearn RandomForestRegressor discrepancy in the displayed tree values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920980/sklearn-randomforestregressor-discrepancy-in-the-displayed-tree-values)
- [Why does this decision tree's values at each step not sum to the number of samples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103507/why-does-this-decision-trees-values-at-each-step-not-sum-to-the-number-of-sampl)